# ruby on rails - has_many attribute validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I perform validations checks (and insert error messages into an errors structure) on an attribute which is has_one association.

If an error has occured in "shirt" or "pants", how can i access that error?
Will the error be in person.shirt.errors[:color] ?

When i trigger person.save, are validations for person.shirt activated?

When i trigger person.save and there is an error in person.shirt, where will the error message be saved? In person.shirt.errors or in person.errors?

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one   : shirt
      has_many  : pants
      validates :name, :presence => true
      validates_length_of :name, :minimum => 3
end

person = Person.new(:name => "JD")
person.shirt.create(:color=> "red")
person.pants.create(:type=> "jeans")
person.valid?
```

Comment: for some reason i am not able to add a comment to the previous answer, so i am writing my comment in here.

edgarjs (or anyone else), last question about this manner.
If the error is within the pants[2].color , the error will appear in `person.errors.at(:shirt[2].color)` or `person.errors.at(:shirt[2])` or prehaps both cases ? 

How do i reach an error message of an has_many association object ?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate an association of the model with

```
validates_associated :shirt
```

That way when you call `person.save` it will trigger the validations of `shirt`.

And yes, you can access the association's error with `person.shirt.errors` but be sure to do that after triggering validations. For example:

```
person = Person.new
person.errors # => will be empty
```

This is because validations haven't been ran yet. So you need to call either `save` or `valid?` or any other method that triggers validations.

```
person = Person.new
person.valid?
person.errors # => will have errors in person
```

And it's the same for the associations:

```
person.shirt.valid?
person.shirt.errors
```

but since you're validating the associations with `validates_associated` it will be enough with `person.valid?` to trigger shirt's validations.

Comment: edgarjs thx for the respond. If the error is in shirt, will it also appear in person.errors ?

Comment: edgarjs, did you had a change to look at my comment ?

Comment: Sorry, just read your comment. If the error is in shirt, it will appear in person as "shirt is not valid" but no more details, however you can always access `person.shirt.errors` to get shirt's error.